# Power button doesn't work in WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power, shutdown, button-remapping

So I have a dell notebook which doesn't shut down when I press the power button. I can select shutdown from the Start Menu though.

I think it's a software problem because I can turn on the computer using the same button :s

I looked into "Power options > Choose what the power buttons do" and "Shutdown" is selected

Answer (score 0):

On which of the power plans did u set ur power botton to shutdown? Take note; when you tap your battery icon on the computer screen,>select more options>tap the "choose what the power bottons do" and then it select shutdown if you want to activate it on battery or when plugged in, or for both conditions.